# Defining E-mail as PK in django-restframework and admin panel

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and Django rest framework.

I have two issues:
1. Django's auth.User comes with an id field. I would prefer to simply work with the email as the primary key, how can I do that?

2. when I try to create a new Project using the admin site, I get this error:

**(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_lab_rat`.`researchproject_project`, CONSTRAINT `researchproject_proj_lead_researcher_id_cdf43d86_fk_researchp` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_researcher_id`) REFERENCES `researchproject_user` (`email`)')**

I think that the admin panel sends the email instead of the id in order to create the Project for the lead_researcher property. any idea how to solve this?

The Project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, default='new project')
    study_goal = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    animal_welfare = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date(), null=False)
    d = timezone.timedelta(days=30)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date() + d, null=False)
    due_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date() + d, null=False)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lead_researcher = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lead_researcher')
    participating_researcher = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='participating_researcher', null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'start_date'),)
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['lead_researcher', 'is_done']),
            models.Index(fields=['participating_researcher', 'is_done'])
        ]
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't overwrite default primary key. its cause to duplicasy error or create problems with big db. Use Serializer to return object withour ids or remove other fields if you required.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta(object):
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'stdy_goal', 'animal_welfare', 'start_date')
```

and also indexing on bolean field is not preferable and not a good practice.

Comment: OK! in the end I used the regular django user - and removed the boolean indexing.